# Selenium 2.0b3, deal with tinymce in IE9

Tags: tinymce, internet-explorer-9, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium 2.0b3 and ruby to test send email function with tinymce and this is my problem: I can't type text into tinymce text area. Here is my code:

```
select_frame("message_content_ifr")
focus("tinymce")
type("tinymce", "test")
select_frame("relative=parent")
```

It still works fine with firefox 3.6.8 but not with IE9. As I see, select_frame() and focus() work but can't type any text into the area.

Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: can you post your full tinymce init? and which tinymce version you are using?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution using rspec/selenium for IE8. select_frame/focus/type.... works in Firefox and Chrome, but would not work in IE.

This line is calling javascript:

```
page.get_eval("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Replace with your text')")
```

Comment: I had to modify it a bit for my case (Firefox 16.0, Selenium IDE 1.9.0, tinymce: 3.5.7): command: `runScript`, target: `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(‘Replace with your text’)`

Answer (score 0):

try to use something else xpath ,
Ex: `type("name=tinymce", "test")`

Comment: Since TinyMCE 3.4.x doesn't work anymore. See comments in http://nickbartlett.com/wordpress/selenium-ide-and-tinymce/